# FIRAuth.auth() compiling error: "Cannot use optional chaining on non optional value 'FIRAuth'"

Tags: swift, swift2, firebase-authentication, ios9, xcode7

Cannot use optional chaining on non optional value 'FIRAuth'

I have tested every solutions, but always got the same error.
Even if i create a new project, when i'm using FIRAuth, i always got a compiling error.

Can someone help me please. I use Swift 2, Xcode 7, IOS9

Comment: Please why are you still you using swift 2, please update to swift 3.0 at least so you could use the new `firebase api`. where you would use `Auth` instead of FIRAuth

Comment: I can't upgrade with my mac for the moment, sadly. There is less problems with swift 3 and the Auth class?

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to add `FIRAuth.auth()?` try to remove (?).

[FIRAuth.auth()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/FIRAuth#/c:objc(cs)FIRAuth(cm)auth) is non optional so treating them as one might result to the error “Cannot use optional chaining on non optional value 'FIRAuth'”

> Optional chaining is a process for querying and calling properties,
>   methods, and subscripts on an optional that might currently be nil

Check [Optional Chaining](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Beyond that your answer rather reads like a mediocre comment, not like a real answer to the question.